# How to install/add patchdiff in IDA?

Tags: installation, diff, patch, ida

I download IDA Demo and IDA Free versions, and patchdiff package which contains two files - patchdiff2.p64 and patchdiff2.plw. So, how I add this future into IDA? How I can link their? I want compare 2 binary files, which results I will be see in graph. How can I achieve that? Anybody help me please? Or anybody who have bindiff tool and help me with compare my files? Excuse my english. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Copy `patchdiff2.p64` and `patchdiff2.plw` to *`<IDADIR>/plugins`*.

Run IDA.
Now generate an `idb` for both the primary and secondary binaries. Open the primary `idb`. Go to plugins -> Patchdiff2.

It will prompt for the secondary `idb`. Open it and wait for the diffing complete.

The results will be shown in the main IDA window.